# Inserting multiple image names into database using an array

Tags: php, arrays, database, mysqli

I already have a code - check below. This code works fine but I just realised it only adds the files into the uploads folder and doesn't add anything to the Database. Can someone just help me fill out the blank? I'd like to use an array and have it as simple as possible.

Please scroll down to the comment where the code is executed and the image goes into the folder.

**uploader.php**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$j = 0;     // Variable for indexing uploaded image.

$target_path = "uploads/test/";     // Declaring Path for uploaded images.

for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++) {
// Loop to get individual element from the array

$validextensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png");      
// Extensions which are allowed.

$ext = explode('.', basename($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]));   
// Explode file name from dot(.)

$file_extension = end($ext); 
// Store extensions in the variable.

$target_path = $target_path . md5(uniqid()) . "." . $ext[count($ext) - 1];
// Set the target path with a new name of image.

$j = $j + 1;      
// Increment the number of uploaded images according to the files in array.

if (($_FILES["file"]["size"][$i] < 100000)     
// Approx. 100kb files can be uploaded.

&& in_array($file_extension, $validextensions)) {

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_path)) {
// If file moved to uploads folder.

?>

<div id="noerror">Image <?php echo $j;?>-->Image Uploaded!</div>

<?php

// File was moved, so execute code here

// In this code I would like to add file name to a DB 


} else {     //  If File Was Not Moved.
?>

<div id="error">Image <?php echo $j;?>--> <b>Please Try Again!</b></div>

<?php
}

} else {     //   If File Size And File Type Was Incorrect.
?>

<div id="error">Image <?php echo $j;?>--> <b>Check file Size or Type</b></div>

<?php
}
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this:

Please add your `database field names` and `database table name` in the below query:

```
mysqli_query("INSERT INTO `images` SET `image_name` = '".$_FILES['file']['name'][$i]."'") or die (mysqli_error());
```

Your code should be now:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$j = 0;     // Variable for indexing uploaded image.

$target_path = "uploads/test/";     // Declaring Path for uploaded images.

for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++) {
// Loop to get individual element from the array

$validextensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png");      
// Extensions which are allowed.

$ext = explode('.', basename($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]));   
// Explode file name from dot(.)

$file_extension = end($ext); 
// Store extensions in the variable.

$target_path = $target_path . md5(uniqid()) . "." . $ext[count($ext) - 1];
// Set the target path with a new name of image.

$j = $j + 1;      
// Increment the number of uploaded images according to the files in array.

if (($_FILES["file"]["size"][$i] < 100000)     
// Approx. 100kb files can be uploaded.

&& in_array($file_extension, $validextensions)) {

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_path)) {
// If file moved to uploads folder.

?>

<div id="noerror">Image <?php echo $j;?>-->Image Uploaded!</div>

<?php

// File was moved, so execute code here

mysqli_query("INSERT INTO `images` SET `image_name` = '".$_FILES['file']['name'][$i]."'") or die (mysqli_error()); // In this code I would like to add file name to a DB 



} else {     //  If File Was Not Moved.
?>

<div id="error">Image <?php echo $j;?>--> <b>Please Try Again!</b></div>

<?php
}

} else {     //   If File Size And File Type Was Incorrect.
?>

<div id="error">Image <?php echo $j;?>--> <b>Check file Size or Type</b></div>

<?php
}
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Your query line doesn't seem to be working. I tested it with myPHP and it's giving me syntax errors.

Comment: Can you please explain me the error? Did you add database connection file?

Answer (score 0):

Your code was pretty confusing to me because of:

1. No proper indent
2. Comments on the same line as the code are hard to read

Here is what I'd do:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
// Variable for indexing uploaded image.
$j = 0;
// Declaring Path for uploaded images.
$target_path = "uploads/test/";

// Loop to get individual element from the array
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++) {

    // Extensions which are allowed.
    $validextensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png");      

    // Explode file name from dot(.)
    $ext = explode('.', basename($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]));   

    // Store extensions in the variable.
    $file_extension = end($ext); 
    // Set the target path with a new name of image.
    $target_path = $target_path . md5(uniqid()) . "." . $ext[count($ext) - 1];

    // Increment the number of uploaded images according to the files in array.
    $j = $j + 1;      

    if (($_FILES["file"]["size"][$i] < 100000) && in_array($file_extension, $validextensions)) {

        // If file moved to uploads folder.
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_path)) {

            echo '<div id="noerror">Image '.$j.'-->Image Uploaded!</div>';

            // File was moved, so execute code here
            //Connection to DB

            $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "table_name");

            // check connection
            if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
                printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
                exit();
            }

            $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO images_table (img_column_1) VALUES ('".$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i]."')");

            //Close DB connection
            mysqli_close($con);

        //  If File Was Not Moved.
        } else {

            echo '<div id="error">Image '.$j.'--> <b>Please Try Again!</b></div>';
        }

    //If File Size And File Type Was Incorrect.
    } else {   

        echo '<div id="error">Image '.$j.'--> <b>Check file Size or Type</b></div>';

    }  
}
}
?>
```

I usually don't recommend to use:

`echo '<div>'.$var.'</div>'`

But your code was pretty confusing that I feel this is a better solution.

Comment: Your query line is giving me errors, any idea why? Thanks

Comment: I think it has something to do with the brackets or the " '

Comment: OK, edited it so you have the right quotes and single-quotes.
It was all hand-written with no test...